# Today Extension doesn't appear on other devices

Tags: plugins, widget, ios8, provisioning-profile

I'm facing a very weird error, I'm curious if anybody here faced it before. I'm developing a Today Extension, and it works flawlessly on the development device (an iPod Touch), but when I try running it on other devices, the widget has no body, just a title.

All of the devices are registered, and all of them are in the provisioning profile of the app and the extension as well. I tried clean, rebuild, release version, adhoc install, all to no avail. Any idea on what might be wrong? (of course all of the other devices are on the same firmware)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My mistake, be sure to compile for 64 bits as well. :)

Comment: You saved my day, such a ridiculous mistake! :)

Comment: I`m happy you found it useful, took us some headache as well. :)